# Do the Nine Kings of Men still wear the rings after turning into Nazgûl?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

Sauron gave several rings of power to many species that inhabited Middle Earth. The men were the most gullible and had been transformed into wraiths that are loyal to Sauron. After this transformation, did the wraiths continue to wear their rings or did they get rid of them? Or does Sauron need to have the rings on the Nazgûl to maintain his control over them?